# How to add a relationship between tables in LINQ to DB model class

Tags: c#, linq2db

I'm using LINQ to DB (linq2db) and I have a class, Activity.cs which has a Customer property, like this:

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

The Customer class:

```
    public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    [Column(Name = "CustomerId"), NotNull]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
db.Activities.First().Customer.Name  //Returns the customer name of an activity
```

How can I set the relationship between the entities, such that I can do as explained above?

(Yes, I know it doesn't make sense to have the Id field as a string, I have to work against a messy legacy Access database)

Answer (score 2):

If I good understand, one `Activity` has one `Customer`. If so, you should add to your `Activity` class a relation:

```
[Table( Name = "Customers" )]
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    [Column(Name = "CustomerId"), NotNull]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table( Name = "Activities" )]
public class Activity
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    [Column(Name = "ActivityId"), NotNull]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "Customer" )] 
    private int? customerId; 

    private EntityRef<Customer> _customer = new EntityRef<Customer>( );

    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_customer", ThisKey = "customerId" )]
    public Customer Customer{
        get { return _customer.Entity; }
        set { _customer.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

[A good article about this subject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects)

EDIT:

A walk-around when association does not work:

```
[Table( Name = "Activities" )]
public class Activity
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    [Column(Name = "ActivityId"), NotNull]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "CustomerId" )] 
    public int? CustomerId; 

}
```

You can retrieve a customer from activity like this:

```
var activity = db.Activities.FirstOrDefault()
var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id = activity.CustomerId);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However, when I call db.Activities.First().Customer.Name it is always null even when the table has values in it.

Comment: Check associations. Try to give it a name in your database and fill it in the code above. Is customer is null here, or a name?

Comment: Please read this to make it clear: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects

Comment: I've read it and tried to follow the same steps without success. There are no foreign key-relationships between the tables, could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes. Please add it to you database. Then add association name in your database and in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't just edit the database as it's being used by our customers.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can try a walk-around with no association, just with ids.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about the use of [Linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db), not of LinqToSQL. Linq2db is an alternative ORM than supports others database types like Postgresql or SQLite.
Linq2db is optimized for not consume many resources, therefore to attempt to directly access the `db.Activities.First().Customer.Name`, always will throw an exception because it will not load the value of Costomer.

For example, if we use the following code to query the Customers of the Northwind database,

```
using (var db = new NorthwindDB())
        {
            var q = from c in db.Customers
                    select c;
        }
```

It would generate a SQL query like the following:

```
{-- NorthwindDB SqlServer.2008
SELECT
    [t1].[CustomerID],
    [t1].[CompanyName],
    [t1].[ContactName],
    [t1].[ContactTitle],
    [t1].[Address],
    [t1].[City],
    [t1].[Region],
    [t1].[PostalCode],
    [t1].[Country],
    [t1].[Phone],
    [t1].[Fax]
FROM
    [dbo].[Customers] [t1]
}
```

Although the `Customer` entity has a one-to-many relationship with the `Order` entity they are not going to load these values. For the case that we want to get their Customer Orders, I recommend using an unknown type (or simple class) as the following query.

```
using (var db = new NorthwindDB())
        {
            var q = from c in db.Customers
                    select new
                    {
                        c.CompanyName,
                        EmployeeName = c.Orders.First().Employee.FirstName
                    };
        }
```

It would generate a SQL query like the following:

```
{-- NorthwindDB SqlServer.2008
SELECT
    [t4].[CompanyName],
    [t3].[FirstName] as [FirstName1],
    [t3].[c1] as [c11]
FROM
    [dbo].[Customers] [t4]
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP (1)
                [t1].[FirstName],
                1 as [c1]
            FROM
                [dbo].[Orders] [t2]
                    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Employees] [t1] ON [t2].[EmployeeID] = [t1].[EmployeeID]
            WHERE
                [t4].[CustomerID] = [t2].[CustomerID]
        ) [t3]
}
```